# Is it possible to prevent external scripts from being inlined with polymer-cli?

Tags: polymer, polymer-cli, vulcanize

We're using polymer-cli to do our polymer app builds.

I've previously used vulcanize directly with a project that used just a few Polymer components, and it had flags to inline external scripts and to exclude some scripts from being inlined.

```
--inline-scripts
--exclude
```

However, I don't see a way to utilize those flags with the polymer-cli which I think is using polymer-build which is using vulcanize?

The reason I want this is to make it easier to debug some issues in a production bundle/build.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to use source maps too, but even just being able to debug the minified code using Chrome's pretty print would be be better than nothing.

I noticed that polymer-build seems to be switching over to polymer-bundler - maybe vulcanize has been renamed to polymer-bundler but same question applies

Comment: I'm using polymer-build and it has an --inline-script option that is supposed to turn in-lining scripts on, but it appears to not work correctly yet as it always inlines it.